# how to graph B?

Tags: convex-analysis

Good evening,

Exercise

Set 
$B=\left\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\mid x^2+y^2-2y≤0\right\}$.

1) Using the definition of a convex set, study the convexity of $B$.

2) Graphically represent $B$.

Comment: What have you done already? Where do you encounter difficulties?

Comment: my problem is question 2. how to graph B?

Comment: **Hint:**
Observe that
$$x^2+y^2-2y\le 0\quad\iff\quad x^2+y^2-2y+1\le 1\quad\iff\quad x^2+(y-1)^2\le 1$$

Comment: OKAY. Thank you very much for the help. good night